# How to get what are the items collapsed in gantt highcharts-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using Highchart-angular gantt (Latest version)
My intention is to re-create the chart periodically , for this to happen i need to know which category(y axis) is expanded or collapsed by user.

I have already tried getting this.chart.series.data[0].collapsed property where this is static if the initially value is true this will always be true and same if it is false.

Summary : To get collapsed property value against y axis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are referring to is just used for inizialitazion and is not updated.

You can get which elements are actually visible (the name of the category) using the property `ticks` in the `yAxis`.

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/srfv1utc/) | [REFERENCE](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11339#issuecomment-509244987)

Comment: is there a way to identity which is parent and child through the reference/example you specified